WireGuard VPN Client Does Not Connect Remotely
I’ve been trying to set up remote access between my Wireguard VPN server and the client PCs.
Setup:

Server: Ubuntu PC configured as a WireGuard server.
Client: Another Ubuntu PC configured as a WireGuard client.

Problem:
When both the server and client are connected to the same WiFi, they can ping each other's VPN IP addresses, and the client maintains its internet connection. However, when the client connects to a different WiFi network (e.g., my iPhone’s personal hotspot) to test remote access, the client loses its internet connection and cannot ping the server’s VPN IP address and vice versa.
The schema of my network:
vpn network schema
Server configuration (/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf):
[Interface]
PrivateKey = server-privatekey
Address = 10.0.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51820

PostUp = iptables -w -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp0s20f3 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -w -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp0s20f3 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -w -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wlp0s20f3 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -w -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wlp0s20f3 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = client-publickey
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32


wlp0s20f3 is my public interface on the server side.

I also followed the steps below on the server side:

Enable packet forwarding for ipv4 by uncommenting the line.
$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Allow 51820/udp port for firewall.
$ sudo ufw allow 51820/udp

Add a rule to allow port forwarding in the TP-Link router dashboard:
Wireguard Server Internal IP (192.168…), internal/external port: 51820/udp


Client configuration (etc/wireguard/wg0.conf):
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
PrivateKey = <client-privatekey>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <server-publickey>
Endpoint = <server-public-ip-address>:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
PersistentKeepalive = 20 

I obtain the server-public-ip-address using:
$ curl ipv4.icanhazip.com 
Wireguard activation both sides:
$ sudo wg-quick up wg0 
Then I try to verify the connection by pinging each other’s vpn address:
From client:
$ ping 10.0.0.1 
From server:
$ ping 10.0.0.2 
Issue:
Same Network: Works (both PCs can ping each other).
Different Network: Client loses internet connection and cannot ping the server.
(For info, I tried piVPN solution to generate automatically the .conf files. Using pivpn -d (debugging) didn't work either.)
What could be causing the client to lose its internet connection and fail to ping the server when on a different network? How can I fix this issue to enable remote access?
